# Embed aspx site in joomla article

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, web, joomla

I have aquestion about some embeding. I have 2 sites. One that is a joomla site , and one with ticketing and hotels search, whitch uses aspx. 
I have tried to embed the aspx webpage in a iframe, in a wrapper and even made a link to the site with aspx from my joomla site. The thing is , that the site requires autenthication when accesing the link from my joomla site. If i access the link directly is not requiring the login form. What is the best solution to access the aspx site with the ticketing and hotels modules from my joomla site ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide `username` and `password` on url and in your `aspx` web page you can check that username and password for specific user. If username and password is true for including, you can allow request to fetch your web site data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you give me an example of the code please?